# open pdf using Pydrive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I was wondering if I could open a pdf from my google drive to a certain page on a browser tab using Pydrive. I saw threads where uploading and downloading files was possible so I assumed that simply opening files would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyDrive library to upload or download any docs from google drive. I recommend you to go through the link below and see how it goes.
https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/

Comment: I've gone through the document and there seems to be no indication to if you can open files